# Internationalization in Axis2 clients

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-axis, webservice-client

I have the following code in my webservice

```
package com.manumehrotra.hs.samples.internationalization;

import java.util.MissingResourceException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext;
import org.apache.axis2.i18n.Messages;
import org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants;

public class SampleInternationalizationHS {
    public String getInternationalizedMessage(){
        System.out.println("in getInternationalizedMessage");
        String retVal = null;
        String language = null;

        // Get the current MessageContext  
        MessageContext msgContext = MessageContext.getCurrentMessageContext();
        // Get HttpServletRequest from Message Context  
        Object requestProperty = msgContext.getProperty(HTTPConstants.MC_HTTP_SERVLETREQUEST);
        if (requestProperty != null  && requestProperty instanceof HttpServletRequest) {      
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) requestProperty;  
            language = request.getLocale().getLanguage();  
            // language codes are available at - http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php
        }

        System.out.println(language);

        String msg_key = "samplemsg_en";
        try {
            msg_key = "samplemsg_"+language;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            msg_key = "samplemsg_en";
        }

        System.out.println(msg_key);

        try {
            retVal = Messages.getMessage(msg_key, "Jack");
        } catch (MissingResourceException mre) {
            // do nothing...
            System.out.println("resource not found");
        }
        System.out.println("returning "+retVal);
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

I want to know how to set different locale values in my java client so that the webservice code mentioned above recognizes it.

Currently only "en" is being recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Following code can be used to set locale in SOAP headers at the client

```
ServiceClient client = stub._getServiceClient();
OMFactory omFactory = OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory();
OMElement omElement = omFactory.createOMElement(new QName("http://www.w3.org/2005/09/ws-i18n","locale", "i18n"));
omElement.setText("en");
client.addHeader(omElement);
```

and for retrieving locale on server side the following code is used

```
SOAPHeader header = MessageContext.getCurrentMessageContext().getEnvelope().getHeader();
OMElement firstChildWithName = header.getFirstChildWithName(new QName("http://www.w3.org/2005/09/ws-i18n","locale","i18n"));
if (firstChildWithName != null) {
    String locale = firstChildWithName.getText();
    System.out.println(locale);
    if(locale!=null)
        language = locale.trim();
    else
        language="en";
}
```

I have tried the same with a sample webservice and webservice client and it works.